# 100 digit floating point python

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I have a large decimal number, such as the square root of 2, and I want to view the first 100 decimal digits. However, float does not support this capability: `1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

What is the best way to do this? I do not want to import anything, preferably

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to import `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: Take a look at this website: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The mpmath module will also work for this, http://mpmath.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your requirement for precision is 100 decimal digits, I think you have to use `decimal.Decimal`.

The `float` in `Python` is not designed for this kind of precise calculation.

Using `decimal.Decimal` is almost as simple as `float`, you can do `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and some other commonly used calculations directly between any `decimal.Decimal` without any consideration.

Also, `decimal.Decimal` supports setting up the precision directly you want:

```
>>> from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

You can find more detail in this [Python2 API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) or [Python3 API](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#module-decimal)

Comment: You should be passing strings

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: No, it really is floating-point, as the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) say: "The decimal module provides support for decimal floating point arithmetic."

Comment: Can it do square roots though?

Comment: @plugwash [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#decimal.Decimal.sqrt).